# Can't get jquery to display a div, via a param

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-4, coffeescript

got myself I bit stuck. I have a dynamic menu built, and what I would like is for a set of menu options to appear when clicking a heading on the menu. I can't get it to appear.

To start with I display the menu in full. The structure of each section is as follows (where ora is the variable that increments for each menu item)

```
<div style="border: 1px solid dodgerblue; border-radius: 15px; false">
    <li class="heading">
      <a style="margin-left: 0px; text-align: center" class="nav_sectionlink" data-ora="1" href="#">Service Lead</a>
    </li>
    <div id="nav_options_ora-1" class="nav_options">
        <li><a href="/activities"><i class="fa fa-cogs fa-fa-fw"></i> &nbsp;Activities</a></li>
        <li><a href="/calendar"><i class="fa fa-calendar fa-fa-fw"></i> &nbsp;Calendar</a></li>
        <li><a href="/fav"><i class="fa fa-star-o fa-fa-fw"></i> &nbsp;Favourites</a></li>
        <li><a href="/procedures"><i class="fa fa-tasks fa-fa-fw"></i> &nbsp;Procedures</a></li>
    </div>
  </div>
```

I then, via jquery (coffeescript) hide all of the details, via:

```
$ ->
  $(".nav_options").hide()
```

Which works fine. I'm then trying to selectively show, based on clicking of the links enclosed in the heading. I try this via:

```
$ ->
  $(".nav_sectionlink").click  ->
    $('#nav_options_ora-' + $(this).data('ora')).show()
```

Now I can see that I am getting the correct data attribute, based on alerts I've put in, and that in this instance it seems to match, but I can't see the result in the screen.

-- edit -- and this is what a pulled from chrome as the javascript:

```
$(function() {
  return $(".nav_options").hide();
});

$(function() {
  return $(".nav_sectionlink").click(function() {
    return $('#nav_options_ora-' + $(this).data('ora')).show();
  });
});
```

Comment: Is solution in jquery acceptable?

Comment: The exact soln in jquery works for me. You should check the compiled js. Can you add that here?

Comment: Yep, that would be fine, I'll work with what I get! Thanks!

Comment: Here I built a JsFiddle for you https://jsfiddle.net/RajReddy/suumgtvu/. And its the exact same code of what you have. Not sure if its some coffeescript typo error

Comment: Just added the compiled javascript, pulled from chrome dev console - I'll check the fiddle now

Comment: Right - the fiddle works, exactly as I wanted, so many thanks for that, I imported the raw javascript into my coffeescript, (as it can be embedded with back ticks), confirmed it matches in chrome, and it doesn't run. Very odd, I must have something conflicting somewhere (this is on top of Rails 4, and I'm guessing there must be something else in the voluminous javascript conflicting, somehow..  I'll start with checking naming and work my way on from there..

Comment: I'm such an idiot. :-(. I'd just implemented a sliding menu for small screen, where the navigation pulls out. The way foundation 5 does it, means I've display the nav in two places, but only one shows. I was changing one, but the wrong one. I've changed it to class selectors, and it works. Thanks so much all.